# Rename email message name from auto generated GUID to my own value .Net

Tags: asp.net

Let me explain first what i'm trying to do : 
I used SmtpClient to save emails in a folder instead of sending them but the name is auto generated.
I make this in web.config, this is my code :

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
            <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="X:\Mails\"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

How can i rename email message ? It is possible to format the name in web.config ?

Thanks in advance for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use reflection in code to access that property and change it. There is a nice extension method and details on how to use it here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32434/Adding-Save-functionality-to-Microsoft-Net-Mail-Ma

You can pass your own `filename` value which will replace the Guid and generate an email at the designate location with the right name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see this but i was wondering if it's possible to do this in web.config. Apparently no.

Comment: As i said, no. You need to use reflection in order to change the default behavior of the built-in SMTP client. Or you can roll out your own Smtp client implementation that will accept web.config parameters. Please mark as answered if this covers your question. Thanks